# How to put pandas df column values into extract regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am wondering how to pass pandas data frame column values into a regular expression. I have tried the below but get "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

Im after the result below. (I could just use a different regex but was wondering how this might be done dynamically)

Thoughts appreciated :)

```
to_search     search_string  search_result
ABC-T3-123    ABC            ABC-T3
ABC-T2-123    ABC            ABC-T3
DEF-T1-123    ABC            DEF-T1
```

````
import pandas as pd
  
# create list for data frame
data = [['ABC-T3-123', 'ABC'], ['ABC-T2-123', 'ABC'], ['DEF-T1-123', 'DEF']]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['to_search', 'search_string'])

df['search_results']=df['to_search'].str.extract("(" + df['search_string'] + "-T[0-9])")}```
````

Comment: You can't do this. :( Instead, how about `.str.extract("(\w+-T[0-9])")`? Even if you could, it would probably be pretty slow because it would be dynamically generating a regular expression for each row.

Comment: Thanks - but a bit to generic. Was hoping for a dynamic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that you want an efficient solution, but typically these pandas functions do not take values such as `Series`es. Here is an `apply`-based solution, which I think, besides simplifying the regular expression, is the only viable solution here:

```
searched = df.apply(lambda row: re.search("(" + row['search_string'] + "-T[0-9])", row['to_search']).group(1), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> searched
0    ABC-T3
1    ABC-T2
2    DEF-T1
dtype: object
```

Comment: ```# create dynamic regex
def fn_dynamic_regex_match(row):
    re_result = re.search("(" + row['search_string'] + "-T[0-9]" ")", row['to_search'])
    if re_result is None:
        return None
    else:
        return re_result.group(0)
    
df['search_results'] = df.apply(fn_dynamic_regex_match, axis=1)```

Comment: Just an update - i was striking a nonetype error when i went to apply in real life - so added something to fix that - see above.